# Export to .pst multiple mailboxes use Veeam o365

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365, veeam

I try to export multiple mailboxes with PowerShell from Veeam o365.
I can use and export a mailbox https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/explorers_powershell/export-vexitem.html?ver=110 (use Example 7)
But I want to export only 100 from 1000, using .csv list or something else. Maybe someone came across such a task and has a ready-made solution?

Comment: See my answer - what you are trying to achieve is impossible. What is your use case? Perhaps there is another way to do so.

Comment: 100 what from 1000 what? Mailboxes? Mails?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to export multiple mailboxes to a single .pst.
You can confirm so by attempting to choose multiple mailboxes in the UI - you won't be able to do this. Thus, PowerShell won't be helpful.
[image: Unable to select multiple mailboxes]